# Visual Studio 2012 Deploying WPF via ClickOnce missing Files

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I have a WPF project that I am ready to deploy using Visual Studio 2012 but I'm running into missing file issues. I've searched for hours to find nothing but incorrect information about VS2k12 not even having ClickOnce support to it being a bug in VS that was claimed to be fixed in an update but people still complain the update didn't fix it.

If I Start the project in VS it runs fine and my test button works as expected.

When I Publish the project, the publish succeeds, running setup.exe installs successfully and program starts to main window fine.

Clicking test button crashes the application on a `FileNotFoundException`.

Line that causes crash:
`streamReader = new StreamReader("ReceiptTemplates/templates.xml");`

FileNotFoundException:

> Could not find file 
>   C:\Users\dirt\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GEDD6PQW.N72\8M9ONPGG.TVB\prof..tion_40c30d08e677b188_0001.0000_985901e6c8ad767f\ **ReceiptTemplates\templates.xml'.**

Exists:
`C:\MyProject\bin\MyMode\ReceiptTemplates\templates.xml`

Confirmed Does Not Exist: `C:\Users\dirt\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GEDD6PQW.N72\8M9ONPGG.TVB\prof..tion_40c30d08e677b188_0001.0000_985901e6c8ad767f\ReceiptTemplates\ReceiptTemplates\templates.xml`

The templates.xml file has a Build Action of `Content`.

Note: There are other folders/files in the ReceiptTemplates folder that are present such as folder/item.html and picture.bmp, just not the templates.xml file that I can tell...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@drch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/955881/drch) for this:

In my case the `ReceiptTemplates/templates.xml` file was set to be a "Data File" and not "Include".

Solution:

**Right click Project -> Properties -> Publish -> Application Files**

Find file causing issue and change it to **Include**

If it says 'Data File' its in the **data** folder
If it says 'Include' its in the **bin** folder

Check in C:\Users\dirt\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data for it ;)